# Seperating Text for CrossAxisAlignment

Tags: flutter

So I am trying to center the main balance text while keeping the amounts in the transaction list where they are. The problem is that when I change L65 CrossAxisAlignment.start to .center, it centers the text in the list below as well. How can I isolate just the upper balance text?

https://github.com/InvertedX/sentinelx/blob/develop/lib/widgets/tx_amount_widget.dart#L65

[app image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzI07.png)

Answer (score 0):

On L70, instead of getting the text-align from `widget.align`, try manually aligning the text to center; `textAlign: TextAlign.center`.

Comment: the alignment doesnt change